# Finding if a value already exists in the indexedDB

Tags: exists, indexeddb

I am working in IndexedDB. I am able to create, populate and delete the values in my jquery mobile app.

Now when I come to a page for the first time I should check whether the value is available in my DB. If so I need to display "Exists" or "Not Exists" if it doesnt. I have written the below code. I have called this function on document.ready.

```
myapp.indexedDB.existsInFavourites = function(value){
    var db = myapp.indexedDB.db;
    var request = db.transaction(["todo"]).objectStore("todo").get(typeid);
    request.onerror = function(event) {
      // Handle errors!
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      // Do something with the request.result!

    };
  }
```

which results me in the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError : Cannot call method 'transaction' of null
```

Any Suggestion would be of great Help. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: That error message suggests that `myapp.indexedDB.db` is `null`, which obviously would preclude you doing a transaction on it. You should fix that problem first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like it is related to the line:

```
var db = myapp.indexedDB.db;
```

You need to connect to the database and then do the work in the callback. Briefly, something like:

```
// var typeid = ...;

// Request a connection
var openRequest = indexedDB.open(name,version);
var openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    // event.target === this and event.target === openRequest
    // so use whatever you prefer

    // Now use the 'db' variable to do the work
    // Note: removed unnecessary brackets around todo
    var getRequest = db.transaction("todo").objectStore("todo").get(typeid);
    getRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
        var myResult = event.target.value;
        // event.target === this, and event.target === getRequest

        console.log('Got %s !', myResult);
    }
}
```